# Laravel orderBy not sorting by product price from max to min

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I want to show the products based on the ascending or descending price, but it does not work. So the first product to be displayed is $19, the second $5, the third $10, etc.

```
public function sort(Category $category)
{
    $products = $category->products()->orderBy('price', 'desc')->get();
    
    return view('products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the `price` column? Is it a float/decimal, or integer? Or a string (varchar, etc)? You might need to A) fix it to be a numeric column or B) cast it to one. Also, a screenshot of your sorted results vs what you're expecting would really help here.

Comment: thank you
fixed
The reason it did not work was that the price was string not integer